# Click event on the map fires two times if google.maps.Rectangle and InfoBox are overlapped

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API v.3 and custom [`InfoBox`](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/infobox/src/infobox.js).

The problem is `Click` event on the map fires two times if `google.maps.Rectangle` and `InfoBox` are overlapped though `pane` of InfoBox is **higher** than `pane` of `google.maps.Rectangle`.

Default `google.maps.InfoWindow` works properly and `click` event don't "percolates" on the underlying elements such as `google.maps.Rectangle`.

I prepared a [small example](http://orbitaria.dev.riaweb.ru/upload/infobox.html) for test purposes.

How can I avoid this percolation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on anything in the map, the click event ["bubbles"](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) up until it reaches the root element of the map. Event handlers there then decide what was clicked on, based on the coordinates of the click.

A way to stop your problem from happening is stopping the click event from reaching the map root.

This is done by calling `event.stopPropagation()` on the event. You could add an event handler that does this; for example on your infobox:

```
var infobox_options = {
    content: '<div onclick="event.stopPropagation()" style="cursor:default;width:100px;height:100px;border:2px solid #000;text-align:center;background:pink;z-index:10;"><a style="z-index:999" target="_blank" href="http://vk.com">CLICK</a></div>',
    disableAutoPan: true,
    //pixelOffset: pixelOffset,
    position: point,
    closeBoxURL: "",
    isHidden: false,
    pane: "floatPane",
};
```

Comment: Thanks, Roman! The joke is I knew about bubbling in JS but I didn't think about it in this case.